# Automatic script Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

How to make sure that every 24 hours run script automatically, which compares the current time with the time that is stored in the database, and if the current time is greater then I need to make changes to the database. I use Codeigniter.

Comment: I don't know how to use it. Is there any easier solution?)

Comment: I was going to suggest CRON too. If you don't know about CRON, now's your time to start researching :)

Comment: Keep in mind if there is no service that will provide you to run job at certain conditions you are "lost". `CodeIgniter` and any other framework in PHP is client-server based. If you run win7+ workstation you are able to use "job" also command for this is `at`, but `CRON` (every hosting should provide this service) is the way to go.

Comment: To add to @Kyslik comment  > AT is a windows Task Scheduler Command, this is used instead of > cron on a windows development env http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726974.aspx

Answer (score 0):

CRON Jobs is the solution, but it is not script, it's server based application that runs every given time. You can setup it from hosting panel, but not all of the hosting providers support it :(